# Strange artefacts on LCD display being driven by FPGA

Tags: fpga, lcd

I'm trying to use a Tang Nano 9K FPGA to generate a good signal for a 4.3 inch LCD display with a 40-pin connector.

If I display a checkerboard image like this

[image]

then all is well.

This code generates the checkerboard. `LCD_DEN[0]` is the display enable and `pixel_x[10:0]`,`pixel_y[10:0]` are the current pixel coordinate. `LCD_R[4:0]`, `LCD_G[5:0]`, `LCD_B[4:0]` are the outputs.

```
`define OFF5 5'b00000
`define OFF6 6'b000000

`define BG5 5'b00000
`define BG6 6'b000000

`define ON5 5'b11111
`define ON6 6'b111111

assign LCD_R =  !LCD_DEN                                        ?   `OFF5   :
                pixel_x[5] ^ pixel_y[5]                         ?   `ON5    :
                                                                    `OFF5   ;

assign LCD_G =  !LCD_DEN                                        ?   `OFF6   :
                pixel_x[6] ^ pixel_y[6]                         ?   `ON6    :
                                                                    `OFF6   ;

assign LCD_B =  !LCD_DEN                                        ?   `OFF5   :
                pixel_x[7] ^ pixel_y[7]                         ?   `ON5    :
                                                                    `OFF5   ;
```

But if I change it so that only a portion of the screen is covered with the checkerboard, then I get some strange artefacts.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzhrYD-FGOs

Interestingly, if I set the background (where the checkerboard is suppressed) to white, these artefacts disappear.

I tried many combinations of lcd signal configurations and timings but nothing fixes it.

The LCD driver code is [here](https://github.com/cskilbeck/fpga_lcd/blob/a96509ec731b42b247f96d88769e3923c38d81f7/lcd_driver.v). Also of note, I get artefacts (similar but different) on another display which is 800x480.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aha, looking at the schematic, it seems the red (and some of the green) bits have 100nF capacitors on them (they're shared with the HDMI and they added these DC blocking caps). We have a suspect...

Comment: And we have a winner! Removing the capacitors eliminates the artefacts completely.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to some capacitors on the dev board. We can see from the schematic (available at https://dl.sipeed.com/shareURL/TANG/Nano%209K/2_Schematic) that these capacitors would soak up signal transitions on all the red and some of the green pins. Removing the capacitors does make the HDMI connector non-functional (but it's kind of useless anyway) but does allow you to drive an RGB screen.

**Schematic overview**

[image: Overview]

**Connector**

[image: Connector]

**Capacitors**

[image: Capacitors]

Comment: It's too late for this unit, but did you consider the capacitance of the breadboard rails? The RGB pins are also shared on the connectors which now plugged into the breadboard, and it adds extra capacitive load to the signals too. If you have another unmodified Tang Nano 9K it's worth testing your problem without breadboard.

Comment: Good point, I can put one back on the MSB of the red and check, thanks for the suggestion